# How to cite a SSRN paper in master thesis?

Tags: citations, citation-style

How should I cite a paper which I found on https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2580904? In my references, the citation appears like this:

```
Hayes, A. (2015). A cost of production model for Bitcoin. Available at SSRN 2580904.
```

Is **Available at SSRN 2580904** the standard way of citing SSRN papers? I am using APAlike bibliography style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper you linked has a suggested citation at the bottom. One of the choices is a DOI.

> Suggested Citation:
>
> > Hayes, Adam, A Cost of Production Model for Bitcoin (March 19, 2015). Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=2580904 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2580904

This is not APA format, so it needs a bit of reformatting to get it into proper APA 7 format:

- format of author name
- format and placement of date
- casing of article title
- inclusion of journal title
- format of DOI as HTTPS URL

> Hayes, A. (2015). A cost of production model for Bitcoin. *SSRN Electronic Journal*. https://doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2580904